# How to access Index after Pivot using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My DataFrame looks like this :

[image: Initial Dataframe]

```
# Pivoting the DF 
df = df.pivot(index='Date',columns='Track Name',values='Streams')
```

> After pivoting, I cant access the Index key.

The DataFrame looks like this :

[image: After Pivot]

Can any one tell me what am I doing wrong ? I am new with Pandas, reference to helpful recourses is welcome.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Hi using df.index.date solves the issue, but what if the name of the index has space in it , like 'date of purchase' ? Then how to access it ?

Comment: @Erfan the error is KeyError: 'Date'

Comment: Let me know if my answer suits your needs.

Comment: @MariosKaramanis it helped me, but I want to access by the key name. 
Suppose the name of the index has space in it , like 'date of purchase' 
Then how can it access that? df.index. ?

Comment: Ohh I see, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df.index.values
```

It will return a numpy array of the values of your index column
and you can then slice it like that `df.index.values[0]`.

Or if it is more preferable you convert it to a list:

```
list(df.index.values)
```

Comment: is there any way to access the index using key? like df['Date']